# Как сконвертировать конфигурацию 1с выгруженную в множество файлов в cf-файл

Tags: 1с

В 1с есть функция выгрузки конфигурации в множество файлов, возник вопрос: как можно конвертировать обратно весь этот набор папок в cf файл?

Выгрузка файлов предпочтительнее выгрузке cf файла, потому что cf файл не подходит для git по весу.

Как собрать все эти выгруженные файлы в один cf после клонирования из git?

Comment: пожалуйста укажите именно в вопросе всю информацию.

Comment: не добавляйте пожалуйста метки которые не имеют отношения к решению вопроса. метка битрикс является лишней так как она относится к совершенно другому продукту другой компании. метки git и gihub так же не влияют на решение вопроса. метка на данном ресурсе служит если грубо говорить темой. специалисты сидят в своих темах. указывайте в метках только те, специалисты по которым смогут решить ваш вопрос. в данном случае это метка 1С.

Comment: изобретаю велосипед, ругаться не нужно

Answer (score 2):

Я бы создал пустую базу, открыл бы конфигуратор, загрузил бы конфигурацию из файлов, а затем выгрузил бы её в файл cf

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы загрузить из файлов, напрямую в CF нельзя:
// Загрузка конфигурации из исходников
task loadSrc(type:Exec) {
    workingDir './'
     standardOutput = new ByteArrayOutputStream()
    args = ['DESIGNER', '/F"./db"', '/LoadConfigFromFiles"./target"'];
    executable = 'C:/Program Files (x86)/1cv8/8.3.5.1443/bin/1cv8.exe'